# ASP.Net - How to handle multiple date ranges that must be 1 year total

Tags: jquery, asp.net

User needs to be able to define multiple date ranges that must be 1 year in total.  However, there might be entries that keep the total from adding up to a year and the user needs an easy way of seeing where the "gap" is.

My solution:
Allow users to enter new date ranges as needed
Add up time spans for each.
If there is a "gap" between 2 consecutive time spans, then highlight those two ranges in some fashion in the UI.

thoughts?

Comment: you first share your problem then you answer it and in the end you write _thoughts?_ now whats that suppose to mean? what do you want us to do?

Comment: my answer is more of a suggestion, and im looking for any better suggestions for ways to handle the problem.